# Is it safe to replace a Furnace pressure switch with one of a different rating?

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace, natural-gas, lennox

So I had some problem with my gas furnace and a technician came by to install a new one but it doesn't have the same rating and only has one tube instead of two. He assures me it's fine but I thought all furnace repairs had to be made with OEM parts? Can anyone let me know if this is safe and if it will affect the life of my furnace?

The furnace is a Lennox ML195 Single stage 95% efficiency furnace. He replaced the whole pressure switch but the new one has only one port whereas the old one has two, so now there is a hose that is unconnected on one end. Also the old pressure switch has a rating of 0.90 PF and the new one says 0.27" WC is that the same?

Comment: The 0.90 PF switch has a rating that specifies that it reacts to a Pressure Fall of 0.90 IWC (inches water column). The other one is rated to switch at 0.27 IWC. So they are not the same. IWC is a way of measuring a pressure differences in inches of displacement of a water column on a device called a manometer.

Comment: Please edit your original question, rather than posting a new one.